# Android: How to make app run only on REAL physical mobile devices

Tags: android, react-native

**CONTEXT AND BACKGROUND:**

I have seen many answers answering how to make android run only one app. My question is different in the sense that I want to know how to make my android app run only on **physical** mobile devices.

**SOME DETAILS:**

I am relatively new to mobile app development. My app asks for user's phone number to log-in. My app then shows the user - list of phone numbers on the device and the user selects one.
I am using react - native for mobile development and the particular library I am using is `react-native-sms-retriever` for this.

https://github.com/Bruno-Furtado/react-native-sms-retriever

**MY MAIN CONCERN:**

I think an android app can be made to 'run' on desktop computers or laptops and artificial phone number can be used to log-in. I don't want this to happen. I want the user to log-in from his phone with his **real** phone number.

**WHAT I HAVE THOUGHT (AS A WEAK SOLUTION);**

The `build.gradle` file contains a section:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }
```

In the above it builds for the 4 architectures: `armeabi-v7a, x86, arm64-v8a, x86_64`. Now usually the desktop and laptop run on `x86` or `x86_64`. So would deleting these 2 from the above build.gradle solve my problem? As (I think) the app bundle or apk will not contain binaries for `x86` and `x86_64` ?

**MY QUESTION:**

How to make my android app run only on REAL physical mobile devices so that I may get real phone number when user is logging-in.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check Device REAL(physical) or 
Not you can try this code.

**Code :**

```
public static boolean isEmulator() {
return Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")
        || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown")
        || Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk")
        || Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator")
        || Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86")
        || Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Genymotion")
        || (Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") && Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic"))
        || "google_sdk".equals(Build.PRODUCT);
}
```

**output:** `true` or `false`